# Torch / Lua, how to select a subset of an array or tensor?

Tags: arrays, lua, torch

I'm working on Torch/Lua and have an array `dataset` of 10 elements.

```
dataset = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
```

If I write `dataset[1]`, I can read the structure of the 1st element of the array.

```
th> dataset[1]
11
```

I need to select just 3 elements among all the 10, but I don't know which command to use.
If I were working on Matlab, I would write: `dataset[1:3]`, but here does not work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## In Torch

```
th> x = torch.Tensor{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

To select a range, like the first three, use [the index operator](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-):

```
th> x[{{1,3}}]
1
2
3
```

Where 1 is the 'start' index, and 3 is the 'end' index.

See [Extracting Sub-tensors](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#extracting-sub-tensors) for more alternatives using Tensor.sub and Tensor.narrow

---

## In Lua 5.2 or less

Lua tables, such as your `dataset` variable, do not have a method for selecting sub-ranges.

```
function subrange(t, first, last)
  local sub = {}
  for i=first,last do
    sub[#sub + 1] = t[i]
  end
  return sub
end

dataset = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}

sub = subrange(dataset, 1, 3)
print(unpack(sub))
```

which prints

```
11    12   13
```

---

## In Lua 5.3

In Lua 5.3 you can use [`table.move`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.move).

```
function subrange(t, first, last)
     return table.move(t, first, last, 1, {})
end
```

Comment: Thanks @rpattiso. But how to do it with a simple table?

Comment: @DavideChicco.it  see update for one that creates a new table. Lua's iterators or metatables can be used if you want to avoid copying the values. If you're using torch, tensors are more convenient and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
dataset = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
subdata = { unpack( dataset, 1, 3 ) }
```

it makes a copy of the values of dataset from 1 to 3, so the original dataset can not be modified through subdata. In this aspect, this is different in that way from the tensor solution. Maybe in your case the copy is enough.